# Office 365 - how to get a report of Office installs per user?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, microsoft-office-2013

I'm in need of auditing the number of Office installs each user has installed as well as the computer names where Office Pro Plus has been installed.

I had never noticed a place to run such a report in the past, but figured there might be one.  To my surprise I couldn't find anything in the admin portal.

Then I saw this blog post: [Managing Office 365 ProPlus installations: activating, deactivating, and reactivating](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_resource_kit/archive/2012/11/28/managing-office-365-proplus-installations-activating-deactivating-and-reactivating.aspx) which confirms my frustrations:

[image]

> Only the signed in user can see this information.  **Even if you are the
>   administrator for your organization's Office 365 subscription, you
>   can't see this information in any of your Office 365 administrative
>   views. This also means you can't deactivate a user's installation of
>   Office on a specific computer.**

I understand well enough how Office Pro Plus activation/expiration works on Office 365:

> When a user installs Office on a computer from the Office 365 Portal,
>   and if the user hasn't already installed and activated Office on five
>   other computers, Office is automatically activated. Once the Office
>   installation is activated, the software page in the Office 365 Portal
>   is updated with the name of the computer on which Office was
>   installed.
>
> Every day or every time you launch an Office 365 ProPlus application,
>   it will check whether the individual installation or account has been
>   deactivated. The computer needs to be connected to the Internet at
>   least once every 30 days so that this check can be made. If the
>   computer isn't connected to the Internet within 30 days, Office will
>   end up in reduced functionality mode. In reduced functionality mode,
>   the user will only be able to open and view existing Office files, but
>   will not be able to use most of the other features of the application.

However, I can't seem to find any way of reporting each user's Office installs/activations short of having them show me via their portal login.

So, I'm not hoping too much on this, but maybe one of the MS Office 365 partners/vendors out there has managed to create something to gather this information?

P.S. I'll open a ticket with O365 support as well to ask them...but this seems like something that should be documented here on ServerFault for others to reference.

Comment: This would be very useful we are trying to deploy office 365 in 30 countries and would love to see who as adopted. Is there report of users and last login time??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of 09/11/2018, You can see it in the report section in admin center.

Use the link below,
https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/reportsUsage/OfficeActivations
or go to
 `Admin Center-> Home -> Usage -> Microsoft Office activations`

The chart didn't work when i tested it, but you can export detail in csv file where you will find activation details per user per type of devices (Mac, Win, iOS, Android).

Comment: reassigned answer here.  Thanks KuN.  This is a more concise report, however it doesn't give device name here. It would have been nice to have that in the detailed report.  Maybe in the future.

Comment: We have been able to create a report specific for this in our platform if still needed.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  See Ian's answer...the portal as of 6/9/2016 allows for this now.

FYI, at the moment according to MS Support there isn't a way to create or pull such a report.  If this changes in the future I'll edit this answer...or if someone else finds that it became possible be sure and either edit my answer or post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

They now offer a "Microsoft Office activations" report in the admin portal. It provides per-user data but still fails to list the names of activated hosts/devices. Device/host names with activated installs only appear in the user data area--admins can now see this. (No improvement in the "new" admin center either.)

Answer (score 1):

As of 06/09/2016 the admin portal allows an admin to view the installations per user and the names of the devices. And deactivate them if required.

Comment: Yes. Where? MS UI traditionally bad.

Comment: Go to https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/users (or select `Users -> Active Users` from the main admin portal.)

Select a user and then scroll down to `Office activations -> View ‎Office‎ activations`.